# MediaMetaDataRetActivity - getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am having trouble displaying an MP4 video file using `MediaMetaDataRetActivity`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/adhavan.mp4";
        System.out.println("imagepath"+filepath);
 MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(filepath);
bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(10000 ,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
System.out.println("BITMAP"+bitmap);
       Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_ALBUM: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_ARTIST: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_COMPILATION: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_CD_TRACK_NUMBER));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_COMPILATION: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_COMPILATION));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_DATE: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_DISC_NUMBER: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DISC_NUMBER));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_DURATION: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_GENRE: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_TITLE: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_WRITER: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_WRITER));
        Log.d(TAG, "METADATA_KEY_YEAR: " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_YEAR));
          imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The error I got is `getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is NULL pointer`.  This I got in **Logcat** while running and the screen is blank.

Comment: Should place a valid video file .i.e., a good quality file it will work

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking.

Comment: BlaineOmega I got the answer.Any how thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 4):

Try using OPTIONS_CLOSEST_SYNC instead of OPTIONS_CLOSEST.

Though, this will provide you with a key frame instead of the exact frame.

Answer (score 0):

`adhavan.mp4` might be using a codec that is not [listed as supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).  If that's the case, test with a better video and/or [convert](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1243312) the one you have.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer Hanika. adhavan.mp4 video doesn't support so I changed another video and got the Image perfectly.Any how thanks Hanika

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

Check if you can extract meta data information from the video via `ExtractMetadata`. If not, there might be something wrong with the `setDataSource()` call or the video is in a wrong format/codec.

This code works for me.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd=getAssets().openFd("t.mp4");
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

I had to provide `afd.getStartOffset()` and `afd.getLength()`

Maybe it helps you get on the right track.